# Oracle SQL: "GENERATED ALWAYS" with a specified sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that I would like to let them share the same sequence to populate the primary key `ID` column. However, I also don't want the user to specify or change the value for the `ID` column.

---

By using the code below, I can let two tables share the same sequence.

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    ID INTEGER DEFAULT SEQ_1.nextval NOT NULL
);
```

This code will use its own sequence and prevent users from changing or specifying with `INSERT`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL
);
```

---

Is there a way that can both world? Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( SEQ_1.nextval ) NOT NULL
);
```

---

Regarding the use case, as `@Sujitmohanty30` asked, the reason that I raised this question:

I'm thinking to implement inheritance in the database, consider this [UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRkdN.png) (I can't directly post images due to insufficient reputation, and sorry for being lack of imagination).

`ANIMAL` is abstract and all inheritance is mandatory. This means no instance of `ANIMAL` should be created. Furthermore, there is an one-to-many relationship between `ANIMAL` and `ZOO_KEEPER`.

Therefore, I came up with this idea:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE ANIMAL_ID_SEQ;

CREATE TABLE HORSE
(
    ID     INT DEFAULT ANIMAL_ID_SEQ.nextval NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    HEIGHT DECIMAL(3, 2)                     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE DOLPHIN
(
    ID     INT DEFAULT ANIMAL_ID_SEQ.nextval NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LENGTH DECIMAL(3, 2)                     NOT NULL
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON HORSE WITH ROWID;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON DOLPHIN WITH ROWID;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ANIMAL
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT 'horse' AS TYPE, ROWID AS RID, ID -- TYPE column is used as a UNION ALL marker
FROM HORSE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dolphin' AS TYPE, ROWID AS RID, ID
FROM DOLPHIN;

ALTER TABLE ANIMAL
    ADD CONSTRAINT ANIMAL_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE ZOO_KEEPER
(
    NAME      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ANIMAL_ID INT         NOT NULL REFERENCES ANIMAL (ID)
);
```

In this case, the use of the shared sequence is to avoid collision in `ANIMAL` mview. It uses `DEFAULT` to get the next ID of the shared sequence. However, using `DEFAULT` doesn't prevent users from manually `INSERT`ing the `ID` field or `UPDATE` the value of it.

Comment: What is your use case exactly ? Why not two sequence ? You may have to explain about the use case in detail. what your are trying to achieve gives you no advantage irrespective of its possible or not until you have a specific use case if you can share

Comment: You can specify any sequence attributes you want - `start with`, `increment by`, `cache` etc. See the documentation under [create table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAECCFH). Is the sequence name important?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I updated the description with a use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master view/table and generate the sequence in it.
Then copy it as column values into both tables while inserting.

Another option could be inserting into both tables at same time.Use SEQ.NEXTVAL to insert into first table to get a new ID, and then SEQ.CURRVAL to copy same id in the table.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant have anything like this because ID is independently generated for each of the tables and this can be done only using sequence when you are inserting the data in both the tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data schema: add column animal_type into the table and create composite primary key on both columns